# Inequality. $(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab) \geq abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be three real positive(strictly) numbers. Prove that:

$$(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab) \geq abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$$

I tried :

$$abc\left(a+\frac{bc}{a}\right)\left(b+\frac{ca}{b}\right)\left(c+\frac{ab}{c}\right)\geq abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) $$
and now I want to try to prove that for example $$a+\frac{bc}{a} \geq a+b$$

but I don't know if is is a good idea.

Thanks:)

Comment: The last inequality only holds when $c \geq a$.

Comment: Also you may assume without loss of generality that $c \geq b \geq a$ to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\prod_{cyc}$ refers to the cyclic product of $x, y, z$.
Let $a=x^2, b=y^2, c=z^2$ for positives $x, y, z$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have:
$$LHS^2=\prod_{cyc}[(x^4+y^2z^2)(x^2z^2+y^4)]\ge \prod_{cyc}(x^3z+y^3z)^2=x^2y^2z^2\prod_{cyc}(x^3+y^3)^2$$
Then, by Power-Mean and AM-GM:
$$x^2y^2z^2\prod_{cyc}(x^3+y^3)^2\ge x^2y^2z^2\prod_{cyc}[\frac{(x^2+y^2)^3}{2}]\ge x^2y^2z^2\prod_{cyc}[(x^2+y^2)^2xy]=RHS^2$$
Thus $LHS^2\ge RHS^2$, and both sides are positive so $LHS\ge RHS$ as desired.

Sidenote: There is also a proof by direct expansion in $a, b, c$: upon expanding and rearranging the inequality becomes $\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(\frac{a+b}{2})(c^3+abc)\ge 0$, which is clear.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach that is less intensive. Show that

$$ (a^2 + bc) ( b^2 + ca) \geq ab(c+b)(c+a) $$

This is equivalent to

$$ c (a-b)^2 (a+b) \geq 0 $$

Multiply the 3 cyclic versions of the first inequality, and you get your conclusion. Equality holds if and only if $a=b=c$.

---

Note: The factorization of the second line is easily guessed, by observing the equality holds when $ c = 0, a = b, a = - b$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that we have, from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that
$$(a^2+bc)(b+c)\geq \left(\sqrt{a^2b}+\sqrt{bc^2}\right)^2=b(c+a)^2.$$
Writing the analogous inequalities and multiplying leads to the desired result. Equality holds iff $a=b=c.\Box$

Answer (score 3):

By C-S $$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+bc)=\prod_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+bc)(ac+b^2)}\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{a^3c}+\sqrt{b^3c}\right)=abc\prod_{cyc}(a+b).$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof using the [Reverse Rearrangment Inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/reverse-rearrangement-inequality/).

Observe that with $ a \leq b \leq c$, we have $ bc \leq ca \leq ab $ and $a^2 \leq b^2 \leq c^2$. Hence, applying the RRI on these similarly ordered sequences, we conclude that

$ ( a^2 + bc ) ( b^2 + ca) ( c^2 + ab) \leq ( a^2 + ab)( b^2 + bc)(c^2 + ca) = abc ( a + b)(b+c)(c+a) $.

Comment: A golden solution!  Some orderings should be fixed, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

We have$:$ $$ \left( {a}^{2}+bc \right)  \left( ac+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( ab+{c}^{
2} \right) -abc \left( a+b \right)  \left( b+c \right)  \left( c+a
 \right) $$

$$=ac \left( {b}^{2}+{c}^{2} \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}+ab \left( {a}^{2}+{c}^
{2} \right)  \left( b-c \right) ^{2} +bc \left( {
a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( a-c \right) ^{2}\geqq 0$$
Done.

Comment: Your proof looks nice to me; I suggest mention please the theorem involved in the proof. It looks like SOS.

Answer (score 0):

$$LHS-RHS=abc\sum_{sym} a(a-b)(a-c)+\frac{1}{2}(ab+bc+ca)\left[c^2(a-b)^2+a^2(b-c)^2+b^2(c-a)^2\right]\ge 0$$

True by Schur 3 deg